# What kind of applications are built using Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to know

**Python is suited for what kind of applications?**

I am new to Python world but I know it's a scripting language like Perl but I was not sure about the kind of applications which one would build using Python and would certainly appreciate if someone can provide some useful information.

Comment: @Stackoverflow Readers: Thank you all for providing prompt answer to my query.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's hard to think of kinds of general *applications* where Python would be unsuitable, but there are several kinds where, like just about all higher-level languages akin to it, it might be considered a peculiar and probably inferior choice.

In "hard real time" applications, all dynamic memory allocation and freeing, and *especially* garbage collection, are quite understandably frowned upon; this rules out almost all modern languages (including Python, but also Java, C#, etc, etc), since almost all of them rely on dynamic memory handling and garbage collection of some kind or other.

If you're programming for an "embedded device" which you expect to be produced and sold in huge numbers, every bit of ROM may add measurably to the overall costs, so you want a language focused on squeezing the application down to the last possible bit -- any language that relies on a rich supporting runtime environment or operating system (including Python, and, again, also Java, C#, etc, etc) would no doubt force you to spend extra on many more bits of ROM (consider threaded-interpretive languages like good old Forth: they can make a substantial application's code be measurably more compact than straightforward machine code would!).

There many be other niches that share similar constraints (mostly focused on MEMORY: focus on using as few bits as possible and/or strictly confining execution within precisely predefined limits -- no dynamism, no allocation, no garbage collection, etc, etc), and basically the case would once again incline in similar ways (for example, there are server applications, intended to run on myriads of servers, which can save many megabytes per server if coded in C++ [especially if without "allegedly-smart" pointers;-)] rather than Java, Python, C#, and so on).

Of course there are excellent reasons most modern languages (Python, Java, C#, etc) choose to do dynamic memory allocation, garbage collection, and so forth, despite the importance of application niches where those techniques are a negative aspect: essentially, if you can possibly afford such nice memory handling, writing applications becomes MUCH, MUCH easier, and a whole class of problems and bugs connected with the need to carefully manage memory if you lack such support can go away -- programmer productivity really soars... IF garbage collection and the like can be afforded at all, that is.  For example, if an application was going to run on a few hundreds or thousands of servers, I probably wouldn't bother coding it in C++ with manual memory management in order to save memory; it's only at tens and hundreds of thousands of servers, that the economics of all those extra megabytes really kicks in.

Note that, despite the common misconception that "interpreted languages" (ones with a rich underlying runtime or VM, like Java, C#, Python, etc) "are slow", in fact for most CPU-intensive applications (such as scientific computation), Python is perfectly suitable, as long as the "rich supporting runtime environment" (e.g. `numpy`) is factored in. So, that is not really a factor -- though memory consumption and garbage collection CAN be, in some niches.

Comment: @meder thanks, your summary of "plus" examples was also nice (I focused instead on the "minus" examples because they're so specific and it's easier to explain what makes languages such as Python, Java or C# unsuitable for those specific niches... mostly memory management issues, actually!-)

Comment: Makes sense. My own rule-of-thumb is to not use Python in cases where I'm already worried about whether I'll be able to make it run fast enough in C or C++. In my case, it's realtime DSP work where I avoid Python.

Comment: @Nosredna, if it's _hard_ real-time (no memory allocation or garbage collection allowed), I agree: as I said, I'd definitely avoid Python too. For "just speed" issues, I disagree -- see e.g. http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2008-April/006572.html and the first two links from http://www.astro.cornell.edu/staff/loredo/statpy/ .

Comment: Well, mine is _hard_ real time. I build a DLL that lives in a host. I get some number of samples from one buffer, process them, and write them to another buffer. No pauses allowed. Come to think of it, I don't even know how to build a DLL in Python.

Comment: Building a DLL (be it with COM, IronPython + .NET, etc etc) would be the least of problems -- but with any dynamic-memory, garbage collected language "hard real time" isn't really feasible, so choosing C or C++ (and carefully dealing with your memory by hand) is a good choice.

Comment: Good summary. For pretty much any web application, Python is an excellent choice.

Answer (score 22):

- http://www.python.org/about/apps/
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/Applications

Recap:

- Web Applications ( Django, Pylons )
- Games ( Eve Online - MMORPG )
- Software Development ( Trac for Project Management )
- Object Databases ( ZODB / Durus )
- Network Programming ( Bittorent )
- Mobile applications

And far more...

Comment: Great answer.  I'm glad to know this.

Comment: Trac is not a Desktop software.

Comment: Django and Pylons are web frameworks. No?

Comment: I'd say they're both web apps *and* frameworks. Feel free to edit and correct me.

Answer (score 10):

You say:

> I am new to Python world but I know it's an scripting language.

I think the distinction between "scripting languages" and "programming languages" is quite arbitrary.  Nearly every language developed in the last 10-20 years has some kind of runtime support, usually in the form of a bytecode interpreter or virtual machine.  Python is no different: it gets compiled to bytecode and the bytecode is executed by the Python runtime.  The point is, I would say there are very few things you can do in Java, C#, Ruby, etc., that you **couldn't** do in Python.

That said, however, different languages have different strengths.  So there are certainly some kinds of programs that would be better suited to being written in Python.  It really depends on what you want the programming language to do for you, and what you want to do yourself.  The right answer depends on what kinds of problems you're interested in solving.

Comment: +1 for attempting to dispel the myth that "scripting" languages are somehow different or inferior to other programming languages! I've been fighting this one for 15+ years. :)

Comment: +1 "Dynamic language" is a better category to describe Python.

Comment: @Todd: You are correct that "dynamic language" is a better way to describe Python. However, the static vs. dynamic distinction is completely orthogonal to the concept of "scripting language".  As it happens, most shell languages are dynamic, and people tend to write scripts in shell or shell-like languages, but that really has nothing to do with it *per se*.  As I mentioned, depending on how you look at it, Java could be considered a "scripting" language (because it's bytecode interpreted) but it is certainly *not* a dynamic language (its grammar is very statically typed).

Answer (score 5):

I know its a bit late, but if it helps.

```
Civilization IV
OpenStack
Bazaar
Mercurial
Blender 3D
TwistedMatrix 
Trac
Allura (source project for SourceForge.net)
BitTorrent(<5.3)
Gwibber
Ubuntu Software Center
YUM
OpenERP
journyx
```

Please note that I have avoided the entire race of web-frame works, IDEs (Eric Python IDE, Ninja-ide, PIDA -ide,Wing IDE,Stani's Python Editor and tools ( Pygame, PyGTK, wxPython, mod python, IPython) and webservices  ( youtube.com, reddit.com, quora.com, dropbox.com)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the short answer is, since you mentioned Perl, anything you could build in Perl you could build in Python.  You can build anything in any language, and if the language has easy C bindings, you could even do it efficiently.

Now, this being the case, the question becomes somewhat philosophical.  Python has as a key tenet "*There should only be one way to do it*".  Perl is exactly the opposite.  The key tenet of Perl is "*There Is More Than One Way To Do It*" (TIMTOWTDI) or ( Tim Toady, to his frineds ;) )   How do *you* like to do things?  One clear and shining path, agreed upon by most? Or perhaps you value the almost infinite number of solution paths that any task has in Perl?

So, assuming that your task is I/O bound ( like most things ) rather than CPU bound ( real time programming or games , or nipple crinkling number crunching ) then Python would be suitable.  Whether its philosophy suits *you* is the key question.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the 3d packages these days, such as Maya, SoftImage, Houdini, RealFlow, Blender, etc. all use Python as an embedded scripting and plugin language.

Answer (score 0):

It's computer programming language, and as such any computer program could theoretically could be built with it. See [here for an example](http://www.google.co.nz/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1GGLS_enNZ329NZ329&q=python+large+scale+applications&btnG=Search&meta=)

Answer (score 0):

Bittorrent was built on Python.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Cohen

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Python_software
follow the link and You will see a lot of things. Actually I am also willing to learn Python thats why I have been searching such answers like you and i got this link. Good luck buddy.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.